# Using Angularjs how to bind value in Span

Tags: angularjs

**Here why span is not showing binding values.Here my intenssion is my span has to work as label**

```
<div ng-controller="MydrpCntrl">
        <form>

            <select class="form-control" ng-options="I.EmployeeId as I.EmployeeId for I in EmployeeList" ng-model="EmployeeId" ng-change="GetEmployees()">

                <option value="">Select Employee Id</option>
            </select>
            <span ng-repeat="eee in Emp"> </span>
            <br /><br />
            <table class="table" style="margin-left:20px">
                <tr>
                    <th style="cursor:pointer"<b>Employee Name</b></th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="eee in Emp">
                    <td>
                        {{eee.EmployeeeName}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>    </form>  


    </div>
```

Comment: Well, there is nothing inside your span. Why do you think it should display something?

Comment: As you have it now, nothing will be displayed in the `<span>`.  You need braces inside the span to display data.

Comment: You'll want {{eee}} inside your span, otherwise you're just appending empty spans.

Comment: but here data is comming from dropdownlist so we need iteration process so how we can do it          <span> {{eee}} </span>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<span ng-repeat="eee in Emp">{{eee.Name}} </span>
```